# Install October CMS in a Laravel application

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I want to install October CMS in a laravel application, is the easiest way to install October CMS in the laravel public directory?

I am thinking of terms to make both of these work in a suitable way etc?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

October itself is a laravel app. In fact if you check [here](https://packagist.org/packages/october/october) you'll see that the laravel framework is one of the requirements of OctoberCMS. You can first install October and then migrate the laravel app into the October system. That's the best way to merge them!